# Getting Google Apps Script to Authorize Fusion Table API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I'm building a database that I hope to host in a Fusion Table and I'm developing some test functions for interfacing with the Fusion API. I'm using Google Apps Scripts and have relied heavily on other sources for this code. I've spent most of a day researching this problem and I am now stuck.

When running addNewColumn() in the script editor, it gets to the "fetch ready" log entry (as I can see in the log), it then goes through the authentication process (every time), then just stops (and never gets to the "fetch executed" log entry). There are no errors thrown yet it never completes the fetch command.

When running in debug mode, it goes through authorization then hangs at the fetch line. If i click 'step-in' I get an error that simply says "OAuth Error". I'm not really sure what to do here. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function googleAuth() {
      var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables";
      var service = 'fusion';
      var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(service);
      oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/"+
                 "OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
      oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
      oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('{consumer key}');
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('{secret}');
      return {oAuthServiceName:'fusion', oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}

function addNewColumn(){   
      var p = {
          'name' : "newColumn",
          'type' : "NUMBER"
      };

      Logger.log(addColumn(p));
}


function addColumn(parameters) {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/";
  var fetchArgs = googleAuth(); 

  fetchArgs.method = "POST";
  fetchArgs.payload = parameters;

  //if the fetch arg payload is set to null it will add an unnamed column
  //fetchArgs.payload = null;  

  url += "tables/"+"{table id}"+"/columns";
  url += '?key='+"{key}";

  Logger.log("fetch ready");

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText();

  Logger.log("fetch executed");

  return Utilities.jsonParse(result);  
}
```

---

**Upate**

I've simplified my functions to test and I've discovered that by simply inserting 'null' in place of the 'payload' variable in the payload field of the options body, the code will successfully create a nameless column in the fusion table. However, when I re-insert the payload variable - it stops working.

When not working, it either: asks to reauthorize every time I run it from the editor, or when run from a web app states "Error Encountered: Authorization is required to perform that action". How does the payload change authorization? I've cut and pasted the exact same payload into the OAuth2.0 playground and it works perfectly. Please help.

```
function googleAuth() {
      var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(service);
      oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/"+
                 "OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=" + scope);
      oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
      oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(clientId);
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(clientSecret);
      return {oAuthServiceName:service, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}

function addColumn() {
  googleAuth();
  var payload = 
    {
      name : "IT WORKED",
      type : "STRING"
    };
  var options =
    {
      "oAuthUseToken":"always",
      "oAuthServiceName":service,
      "method" : "post",
      "payload":payload
    };
  var url = fetchUrl + "tables/" + fusionId + "/columns" + "?key=" + apiKey;
  var fetchResult = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(fetchResult.getContentText());
  return Utilities.jsonParse(fetchResult.getContentText());
}
```

---

**Update #2**

I have found a way that lets it run without any errors but it still does not assign the requested name and type to the new column. The most recent addition was specifying the content type as shown below. By forcing the contentType to 'application' or 'json', it will run but still doesn't pass the payload as intended.

```
  var options =
    {
      "oAuthUseToken":"always",
      "oAuthServiceName":service,
      "method" : "POST",
      "payload" : payload,
      'contentType' : 'application'
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!! The solution was twofold:

1. the payload had to be converted to a string via JSON.stringify()
2. The contentType had to manually be set to "application/json"

This is very different than the multiple tutorials I've found online but wanted to share my working solution.

```
function addColumn(authToken) {
  googleAuth();
  var payload =
    {
      name : 'YES',
      type : 'STRING'
    };
  var options =
    {
      payload : JSON.stringify(payload),
      oAuthUseToken : "always",
      oAuthServiceName : service,
      method : "POST",
      contentType : "application/json"
    };
  var url = fetchUrl + "tables/" + fusionId + "/columns";// + "?key=" + apiKey;
  var fetchResult = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(fetchResult.getHeaders());
  Logger.log(fetchResult.getContentText());
  return Utilities.jsonParse(fetchResult.getContentText());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, trying to get and manipulate data from fusion tables.

There's a fusion table library in Google's notable script library: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/notable-script-libraries?hl=pt-BR

I linked that library, but it seems to be buggy. So (for debugging reasons) i copied the source code to my project and got it work:

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/fusion-tables-class/fusion-source

Maybe you find your answers there.

Comment: Thanks. That site is where I got some of my motivation but it uses client-login and sql (which I believe are deprecated). I'm still struggling with the error.

Comment: Actually, I used that library extensively. Unfortunately it still is a  problem. Please see my updated (and clarified) thread above. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- The reason that this appears to be different that other urlFetch POST
  examples is because Fusion Table Service expects an actual JSON
  payload as the request "BODY".  When you add a JSON object
  (without Stringify) as a "payload", UrlFetchApp will convert each name/value pair
  into a Url-Encoded Request String (i.e.  name=YES&type=STRING).
  However  when Payload is a String (as in your case as you are using
  stringify), UrlFetch will just URL-Encode the String you provide (in
  this case a JSON string).   If you were "POSTING" to a service
  expected name/value parameters, then you would not use Stringify.
- Note: Just so you are aware and to clarify your other related
  question that you posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987295/which-oauth-flow-to-follow-google-apps-script-and-google-fusion-tables-api/15445623#15445623) , you are using Oauth 1.0 in this
  example (addOAuthService only supports Oauth1.0 Endpoints and
  protocols)
- One more Note: You are mixing Utilities.jsonParse and
  JSON.stringify.  I would use JSON.parse to be consistent.