# Which OAuth flow to follow? (Google Apps Script and Google Fusion Tables API)

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I'm in the process of learning how to interface with OAuth. I'm using a fusion table as the back end of a database and then using google apps scripts to interface with that database. Parts of the apps script will run of time scheduled triggers while other parts will be published as a webApp. I've run into some other OAuth issues (see thread link below), but this question is much more fundamental. When reading the Google API OAuth literature, it describes different OAuth flows and I don't know which one my program is. Is my application a "web server application", "client-side", "service account" or what.

Google API OAuth info: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
Other Thread: [Getting Google Apps Script to Authorize Fusion Table API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970059/getting-google-apps-script-to-authorize-fusion-table-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the fact that you install a trigger to run a certain function at certain times has no bearing on which Oauth Flow you should use.
Oauth is used to allow Users of your App to grant your App permission to access certain resources that normally only they would have access to.
When you include certain API calls in an App Script, Google Apps automatically presents the user with a Dialog asking for "Authorization" to use these resources on their behalf.
Therefore, in your use case of an App Script as a Front-End to a Fusion Table, you would not need to use Oauth to get Users to Grant permission.
You can Publish your Script to "act" as the User or as the Script Owner.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, when making an API call through a .fetch, do I need to add an API key to the URL? If so, what style of API key ("Key for browser apps", "Key for server apps", etc.)? My later post shows some code for this. [Link To Post Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970059/getting-google-apps-script-to-authorize-fusion-table-api)

Comment: Based on the link you provided, it appears you figured out the Oauth part.  However a few comments.  The API key has nothing directly to do with Oauth.  They (OAuth and API Keys) are both used as Auth. tools by web services, however they can be used independent of one antoher.  Where  you put your API key in your URL would be defined by that specific API.   Many Services accessed via Oauth are not API's.